# HtmlAgilityPack - loading multiple pages

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I've been playing around with the HtmlAgilityPack for a while, but I've run into a problem regarding the creation of a new HtmlDocument. I have a simple program that gets the data of films on a particular list. Some of the information is retrieved on the list page itself, and the rest is retrieved on the linking page for each item.

The problem i'm having is that for every time I wish to retrieve information from the linked page, i'm creating a new HtmlDocument. When I try to retrieve the complete list of films, the program just hangs on the console window. Here is my code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
public class Scraper
{
    private string _baseUrl = @"http://www.imdb.com";
    private string _startingUrl = @"http://www.imdb.com/chart/top";
    private HtmlWeb _webGet = new HtmlWeb();

    public string StartingUrl
    {
        get { return _startingUrl; }
    }

    public string BaseUrl
    {
        get { return _baseUrl; }
    }

    public HtmlWeb WebGet
    {
        get { return _webGet; }
    }

    public List<Film> GetFilmData()
    {
        var allFilmData = new List<Film>();
        var doc = WebGet.Load(StartingUrl);

        var allFilmsInTable = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='main']/table/tr");

        foreach (var line in allFilmsInTable)
        {
            if (line.PreviousSibling != null)
            {
                var film = new Film();
                film.Title = line.SelectSingleNode(".//td/font/a").InnerHtml;
                film.Url = BaseUrl + line.SelectSingleNode(".//td/font/a").Attributes["href"].Value;
                film.Rating = Convert.ToDecimal(line.SelectSingleNode(".//td[@align='center']/font").InnerText);
                film.RankInTop250 = Convert.ToInt32(line.SelectSingleNode(".//td[@align='right']/font/b").InnerText.Replace(".",string.Empty));


                allFilmData.Add(SingleFilmInformation(film));
            }
        }

        return allFilmData;
    }

    public Film SingleFilmInformation(Film film)
    {
        var singleDoc = WebGet.Load(film.Url);

        film.ReleaseYear = Convert.ToInt32(singleDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//h1[@class='header']/span/a").InnerText);
        film.Director = singleDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@itemprop='director']/a/span").InnerText;

        foreach (var genre in singleDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='infobar']/a/span[@itemprop='genre']"))
        {
            film.Genres.Add(genre.InnerText);
        }

        return film;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The code you give doesn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @SimonMourier - The hanging console window was infact due to the nature of my code. It seems to last 4-5 mins when hit hits 'SingleFilmInformation'. Is there a better way to load a new page to scrape?

Comment: HtmlWeb does nothing fancy. You could try a WebClient call and give the result to a doc.LoadHtml() call just to try.